# i can't put tab in Macro Excel

Tags: excel, vba

im new at macro excel this is my first experience with it.
i m just experiment with it & making my office process easier.
i almost completed the project
but in our process data should matched with two columns usually we done it by sorting but while im operating macro there is no option to put tab between unmatched data

im waiting for ur quick reply ...
please help me.
or give me code for this & explain me pls.

Comment: Please rephrase the question, it is not clear what you are wishing to achieve.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of 'tab' in your context. The only tabs I'm aware of are the worksheets (as parts of a workbook).

Comment: Are you looking to sort and then match two nearly identical columns, inserting blank lines on one of the columns when it does not have a match in the other column? What have you tried so far, and what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

The tab character is Chr(09). You can say "ABC" & Chr(09)